# Correct use of possession for the plural 'ladies'

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

At a clothing store, you might see a sign saying **Men's Clothing**, and the possessive use of the apostrophe correctly indicates that the clothing is suited towards the group "Men" (i.e. more than one man). If the apostrophe was after the 's', i.e. **Mens' Clothing**, it would cause someone proficient with grammar to assume that there exists more than one group of pluralized men to whom the clothing is suited (i.e. tall men, fat men, green men).

An ambiguity arises with the phrase **Ladies' Clothing**. It would seem that this use would conform to the second case above (i.e. as **Mens' Clothing**). This is because there isn't really a word spelled 'ladie' ('y' usually becomes 'ies' in plural), so **Ladie's Clothing** would clearly be incorrect.

So my question is how do you refer to the possession of more than one lady, but not to the possession of more than one group of ladies, and thereby avoid the ambiguity caused when using the phrase **Ladies' Clothing**?

Comment: I'm sure there's no such thing in English as *Ladie's* -- it's definitely ***Ladies' Clothing***.

Answer (score 10):

Your premise is wrong. You would not write *mens'*, because there is no plural *mens* for more than one group of men. It it is not like *boy's* for one boy and *boys'* for more than one boy. *Men* is already plural.

Hence, there is no ambiguity with the men, and for the same reason no ambiguity with the ladies. *Ladies* is the plural form of *lady*, so the apostrophe goes to the right - *ladies'*.

If you are wondering why we don't write *ladies's*, it is because *ladies* is one of the exceptions, along with *girls',  parents',  players',  weeks'* and even *Klingons'*

It can get a bit niggly with names too. *Aristophanes' plays*, but *Jesus's miracles* and (usually) *James's car*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I disagree with your statement that there is no plural 'mens'.  It is certainly possible that a plural of a plural can exist (and if not, ought to exist) with regard to 'mens' and other plural structures.

Comment: @Josh: Can you show us an authentic example that you've encountered, Josh?

Comment: @Josh: While you can make uncountables plural to indicate different types, you can't make plurals plural (other than poetically), because they already are.

Comment: @Josh: Do you mean countries could become countriess and countriesss and so on?

Comment: I have seen *Women's College* in some places, though.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, yes I have encountered the standard usage of 'Ladies' Clothing', but my question / argument is more hypothetical.

Comment: A hypothetical plural of a plural? I am not sure I understand your hypothesis.

Comment: @Josh: Yes, I'm sure you've seen 'Ladies' Clothing'. My question was whether you'd seen an authentic example of the use of 'mens' as a plural plural. You seemed to suggest that such a thing could exist.

Comment: I would add that many people whose name ends in 's' prefer to have the added "'s" after their name. :-)